# What causes Firefox to not show me a new tab? Can this be fixed?

Tags: firefox, bug

I am using Firefox 7.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7. Often times when I make a new window, the tab bar contains only a single "+" tab, even after I got to a URL:

[image: Firefox Screencapture]

If I make new tabs, then I cannot get back to the first tab I created. This is extremely annoying. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Did you try to disable all plugins?

Comment: @patrix: good suggestion. I have FireBug installed, maybe that's what's causing it.